# Error in using persistent data store with COMPOSER REST SERVER

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I tried to setup a persistent data store for REST server but was unable to do it.I am posting the steps which I have followed to do it.

Steps which I followed to set a persistent data store for REST server.

1. Started an instance of MongoDB:
   root@ubuntu:~# docker run -d --name mongo --network composer_default -p     27017:27017 mongo
   dda3340e4daf7b36a244c5f30772f50a4ee1e8f81cc7fc5035f1090cdcf46c58
2. Created a new, empty directory. Created a new file named Dockerfile the new directory, with the following contents:

FROM hyperledger/composer-rest-server

RUN npm install --production loopback-connector-mongodb passport-github && \
    npm cache clean && \
    ln -s node_modules .node_modules

3. Changed into the directory created in step 2, and build the Docker image:
   root@ubuntu:~# cd examples/dir/
   root@ubuntu:~/examples/dir# ls
   Dockerfile  ennvars.txt
   root@ubuntu:~/examples/dir# docker build -t myorg/my-composer-rest-server .
   Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.096 kB
   Step 1/2 : FROM hyperledger/composer-rest-server
   ---> 77cd6a591726
   Step 2/2 : RUN npm install --production loopback-connector-couch passport-github &&     npm cache clean &&     ln -s node_modules .node_modules
   ---> Using cache
   ---> 2ff9537656d1
   Successfully built 2ff9537656d1
   root@ubuntu:~/examples/dir#
4. Created file named ennvars.txt in the same directory.
   The contents are as follows:

   COMPOSER_CONNECTION_PROFILE=hlfv1
   COMPOSER_BUSINESS_NETWORK=blockchainv5
   COMPOSER_ENROLLMENT_ID=admin
   COMPOSER_ENROLLMENT_SECRET=adminpw
   COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=never
   COMPOSER_SECURITY=true
   COMPOSER_CONFIG='{
       "type": "hlfv1",
       "orderers": [
           {
           "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
           }
    ],
       "ca": {
           "url": "http://localhost:7054",
           "name": "ca.example.com"
       },
       "peers": [
           {
           "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
           "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
           }
       ],
       "keyValStore": "/home/ubuntu/.hfc-key-store",
       "channel": "mychannel",
       "mspID": "Org1MSP",
       "timeout": "300"
   }'
   COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
   "db": {
       "name": "db",
       "connector": "mongodb",
       "host": "mongo"
   }
   }'
   COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
   "github": {
       "provider": "github",
       "module": "passport-github",
       "clientID": "a88810855b2bf5d62f97",
       "clientSecret": "f63e3c3c65229dc51f1c8964b05e9717bf246279",
       "authPath": "/auth/github",
       "callbackURL": "/auth/github/callback",
       "successRedirect": "/",
       "failureRedirect": "/"
   }
   }'
5. Loaded the env variables by the following command.
   root@ubuntu:~/examples/dir# source ennvars.txt
6. Started the docker container by the below command

root@ubuntu:~/examples/dir# docker run \
    -d \
    -e COMPOSER_CONNECTION_PROFILE=${COMPOSER_CONNECTION_PROFILE} \
    -e COMPOSER_BUSINESS_NETWORK=${COMPOSER_BUSINESS_NETWORK} \
    -e COMPOSER_ENROLLMENT_ID=${COMPOSER_ENROLLMENT_ID} \
    -e COMPOSER_ENROLLMENT_SECRET=${COMPOSER_ENROLLMENT_SECRET} \
    -e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=${COMPOSER_NAMESPACES} \
    -e COMPOSER_SECURITY=${COMPOSER_SECURITY} \
    -e COMPOSER_CONFIG="${COMPOSER_CONFIG}" \
    -e COMPOSER_DATASOURCES="${COMPOSER_DATASOURCES}" \
    -e COMPOSER_PROVIDERS="${COMPOSER_PROVIDERS}" \
    --name rest \
    --network composer_default \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    myorg/my-composer-rest-server
942eb1bfdbaf5807b1fe2baa2608ab35691e9b6912fb0d3b5362531b8adbdd3a

It got executed successfully. So now I should  be able to access the persistent and secured REST server by going to explorer page of loopback
But when tried to open the above url got the below error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzGdj.png)

Have I missed any step or done something wrong.

Comment: Your link to a document doesn't work. Please post the steps here (as text) so they will be indexed and are searchable.

Comment: It looks like the composer-rest-server is not running on localhost. What host name or IP address did you run it on?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to put `export` in front of the envvars in your envvars.txt file.
2. Check the version of Composer you are running.  `The FROM hyperledger/composer-rest-server` command will pull the latest version of the rest server down, and if your composer version is not updated, the two will be incompatible.